# Chain rule (of differentiation)

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, mathématiques

En anglais, on peut dire *the chain rule (of differentiation of a function composed of two or more functions)*. J'ai constaté que la version homologue française « règle de dérivation en chaîne » ou « règle de la chaîne » est quasiment inconnue des étudiants. Mes collègues locuteurs natifs m'ont recommandé de l'éviter.

Existe-t-il une explication à cela ?

Comment: J'ai étudié un peu la mathématique à l’université, et ont parlait toujours de dérivation des fonctions composées, pour la cause exact que l'expression anglaise na pas été adopté en francais, je ne peut pas dire. (mais je peut comprendre d'évité d'utiliser l'expression, car sa pourrait mélanger ceux qui ne sont pas habituer de l'utiliser)

Comment: @yagmoth555 : Merci. Attention il y a quelques fautes à votre commentaire. On dit plutôt les mathématiques ; l'expression anglaise n'a pas été adoptée ; je peux comprendre ; pour la suite je ne suis pas sûr. Peut-être un locuteur natif pourrait vous corriger. En bref : d'éviter (et pas d'évité). Ça pourrait et pas sa (rule of thumb : sa ne peut pas être remplacé par cela !) ; ne sont pas habitués.

Comment: Hi, I mean I always used the "dérivation de fonctions composées" in my class. I never heard the term chain, chain rule, etc.. so I can't explain why I never heard that expression, but I can understand your coworker(s) to warn you to not use it, as it can be hard for a student to understand the expression, if school book never use it. :)

Comment: Vos collègues locuteurs natifs déconseillent-ils cet usage sans donner de raison ? Il  semble qu'ils devraient être les premiers à vous renseigner.

Comment: @yagmoth555 : Mon commentaire corrige aussi quelques fautes. Attention aux homonymes. (Ça/sa, éviter/evité) et à l'accord du participe passé (à propos, la langue parlée évite la voix passive).

Comment: @LPH Pas d'explication précise. Certains pensent que c'est un anglicisme. D'autres pas sufisaement répandue. Il existe même des collègues qui ne connaissent pas l'expression règle de chaine :-)!

Comment: C'est bien un anglicisme accepté puisqu'il est reconnu par beaucoup de monde en France : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_d%C3%A9rivation_des_fonctions_compos%C3%A9es  https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=r%C3%A8gle+de+la+chaine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La France a une tradition mathématique forte et a encore une école mathématique forte. Contrairement aux autres sciences, on diffusait encore de la recherche en français bien après la seconde guerre mondiale dans certains domaines des mathématiques (notamment la géométrie algébrique). Il y a (au moins en algèbre et en analyse, peut-être moins dans d'autres domaines comme les statistiques) suffisamment d'ouvrages en français pour qu'on n'ait pas besoin de lire l'anglais avant un niveau nettement plus avancé que le premier cycle universitaire. La dernière période de réformes majeures dans la façon de présenter les mathématiques et dans la terminologie est venue sous l'impulsion de [Bourbaki](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki#H%C3%A9ritage_et_influence_en_math%C3%A9matique), qui est francophone. Le français a des termes bien établis et ne cherche pas à les remplacer par les termes anglais (au moins en France, je ne sais pas pour les autres pays francophones).

Il n'y a aucune raison pour que « règle de la chaîne » évoque quelque chose pour un étudiant en mathématiques français, voire peut-être même pour un chercheur dans un domaine peu lié à l'analyse. La [règle pour dériver la composée de deux fonctions](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_d%C3%A9rivation_des_fonctions_compos%C3%A9es) n'a pas de nom particulier. L'article Wikipédia mentionne [actuellement](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_d%C3%A9rivation_des_fonctions_compos%C3%A9es&oldid=155237426) le terme « règle de la chaîne », mais sans référence, et [des commentateurs s'interrogent](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Discussion:Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_d%C3%A9rivation_des_fonctions_compos%C3%A9es&oldid=148341088#Titre) sur le bien-fondé d'inclure cette expression qui semble être un anglicisme. Le terme n'est mentionné ni dans mon édition (un peu vieille) du [*Dictionnaire des mathématiques*](https://www.puf.com/content/Dictionnaire_des_math%C3%A9matiques) de Bouvier et al, ni dans le traité d'analyze de [Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_Schwartz) (tome II, chap. III, §4, « Le théorème de dérivation des applications composées »), ni dans le *[Cours de mathématiques](https://www.amazon.fr/Cours-mathematiques-Analyse-Jean-Marie-Arnaudi%C3%A8s/dp/2040165010)* d'Arnaudiès et Fraysse (tome 2, §IV.6, « Dérivée d'une fonction composée »). Aucun de ces ouvrages ne date du 21<sup>e</sup> siècle, et ces dernières années l'expression semble faire son entrée en France, mais cela reste marginal. Sur [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=d%C3%A9riv%C3%A9e+%22r%C3%A8gle+de+la+cha%C3%AEne%22), il n'y a pas beaucoup de mentions, quasiment exclusivement du 21<sup>e</sup> siècle, et la plupart des auteurs qui mentionnent ce terme soit sont des francophones d'autres pays que la France, soit travaillent dans des domaines plus anglophones comme l'économie.

Le terme ne doit pas être courant chez les Canadiens francophones non plus puisque [TERMIUM](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=CHAIN+RULE+DIFFERENTIATION&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) ne le mentionne pas. (TERMIUM mentionne « règle de conjointe », que je ne connaissais pas et qui a l'air [utilisée exclusivement par le gouvernement Canadien, et ce avec parcimonie](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22r%C3%A8gle+de+conjointe%22+d%C3%A9riv%C3%A9e&oq=%22r%C3%A8gle+de+conjointe%22+d%C3%A9riv%C3%A9e))

Je ne sais pas d'où vient l'expression « *chain rule* ». On dit « *[Kettenregel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettenregel)* » en allemand et le théorème semble avoir été remarqué en premier par Leibniz, mais Leibniz n'écrivait pas en allemand. Quelle que soit son origine, l'expression a pris dans beaucoup de langues, mais pas en français.

À noter qu'en France, en mathématiques, on utilise quasiment exclusivement la notation à la Newton : la dérivée de *f* au point *x* est *f'(x)*. La notation à la Leibniz dy/dx est utilisée par les physiciens et autres scientifiques appliqués, mais pas en mathématiques. Du coup la règle pour dériver des fonctions composées s'écrit *(g∘f)′ = (g′∘f) ⋅ f′*, qui n'a pas l'air plus remarquable que d'autres règles concernant les dérivées, alors qu'avec la notation de Leibniz *dz/dy ⋅ dy/dx = dz/dx* on a l'impression (pas fausse mais pas exacte non plus) qu'il s'agit simplement de simplifier les dy. C'est assez symptomatique de la manière d'enseigner les mathématiques en France qui valorise beaucoup la rigueur, ce qui est tout à fait indiqué en mathématiques mais est quelquefois fait un peu au détriment de l'intuition.

Comment: Plusieurs bémols. A/ *En france on utilise quasi exclusivement la notation à la Newton Newton"* **pour les fonctions à une seule variable**. Dès que la fonction à plusieurs variables, c'est la notation de Leibniz qui, tout au contraire est utilisée exclusivement.

Comment: B/ En corollaire de A, ce n'est qu'au niveau BAC+ que l'on va rencontrer cette *règle de chaîne* Mais différemment en fonction de filières. Très rarement en Prépa MP (car comme expliqué dans le lien communiqué dans ma contribution), cette *règle* ne peut pas être balancée ex abrupto dans une démonstration rigoureuse qui privilégiera certainement une écriture de type 2.8. Alors qu'en prépa PC (où on est moins exigeant vis à vis de la rigueur mathématique), on l'utilise souvent (mais sans effectivement mentionner un nom que... l'on n'a pas appris en maths).

Comment: C/ *"Le théorème semble avoir été remarqué...* Attention : Il ne s'agit en aucun cas d'un **théorème**. Il s'agit tout au plus d'un *corollaire*.

Comment: @aCOSwt A/ ∂f/∂x pour une dérivée partielle, bien sûr. Il n'y a pas trop le choix là. Mais pas de notation dy/dx chez les matheux. B/ Il me semble que c'était au programme de maths de 1ère de mon temps (sans démonstration), mais je suppose que le niveau baisse. En physique mes profs ne se privaient bien sûr pas de simplifier par dy, en nous disant qu'on verrait pourquoi en maths plus tard. C'est quoi une écriture de type 2.8 ?

Comment: C/ Gnî ? J'utilisais évidemment *théorème* au sens d'énoncé démontré (sens courant et sens des logiciens). Mais même dans le sens restreint d'énoncé particulièrement important, je ne vois pas pourquoi ce ne serait pas un théorème, ni de quoi ce serait un corollaire.

Comment: 2.8 se réfère au document dont j'ai donné le lien dans ma contribution. Si on s'y réfère, on trouve p88 l'écriture 2.7 qui elle oui, est un théorème. (Qui peut se démontrer). 2.8 est une autre façon d'écrire ce théorème. (démontrable aussi). Puis tu vois avec 2.9 qui correspond à la règle de chaîne qu'il s'agit d'une simplification de l'écriture de 2.8 obtenue en faisant omission des points d'évaluation. Cette omission rend cette forme rigoureusement indémontrable. Je ne peux remonter à 2.8 (sauf à faire l'hypothèse d'une omission et rajouter des termes livrés à ma seule interprétation)

Comment: 2.9 indémontrable sauf mon interprétation particulière, ce n'est donc pas un théorème. Ce n'est qu'une façon d'écrire (judicieuse car très suggestive et donc mnémotechnique) qui permettra au physicien d'aller vite en besogne dans son exo) mais ne peut donc servir au matheux pour démontrer quoi que ce soit.

Comment: @aCOSwt Je n'ai pas ce livre et Google ne me laisse pas voir la page en question. S'il s'agit de variantes équivalentes, il est bien évident que je ne m'intéresse pas à la formulation exacte, et que quand j'écris ici sur ce forum consacré à la langue, je n'énonce pas le théorème complètement avec toutes les hypothèses nécessaires.

Comment: Je n'ai évidemment pas de problème avec ton dernier commentaire. J'observais seulement que, dans ce  que tu écris dans ta réponse, deux propositions n'étaient pas justes.

Answer (score 3):

Cet éditeur n'étant pas adapté à l'écriture d'équations mathématiques, je te conseille la lecture de ce [cours d'analyse](https://books.google.fr/books?id=GtaDSFURUNAC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) particulièrement aux pages 88, 89 et 90.

Tu y liras des formules que tu connais très bien (2.7, 2.8 et 2.9), 3 façons de dire la même chose, et qui, toutes peuvent s'appeler fort à propos *formules pour la dérivation des fonctions composées*.

**Seule la forme 2.9**, (p 90) parce que suggestive, bien que **moins précise** (ce peut être la raison du conseil de tes collègues), représente la *règle de dérivation en chaîne* (de Leibniz). proprement dit.

Comment: Google ne laisse accéder un visiteur qu'à un nombre limité de pages, donc les lecteurs ne peuvent pas forcément voir la bonne page. Ça dépend combien de pages ils ont déjà vu (surtout que tu ne donnes pas un lien direct, donc il faut chercher un peu), de qui d'autre y accède depuis la même adresse IP, de l'âge du capitaine et je ne sais quoi d'autre. La réponse serait plus compréhensible si tu ne supposais pas que le lecteur a lu le livre, et à vrai dire telle quelle ceci ne répond pas vraiment à la question (je ne sais même pas si ce livre mentionne le terme « règle de chaîne » !).

Comment: @Gilles : Il arrive fréquemment que l'on confonde *"whatever"* avec [écriture_de_whatever]. C'est ce que le livre montre. La *règle de chaîne* n'est qu'une écriture non rigoureuse car présentant des omissions de la formule générale de dérivation. Elle peut donc, grâce à sa forme, présenter un intérêt mnémotechnique mais non servir  de théorème utilisable dans une démonstration mathématique. C'est pourquoi elle n'est pas recommandée. Ce qui, à ma compréhension répond à la question de l'OP